# HTML and JavaScript cant see each other

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm in the middle of a college project and cant for the life of me work out what has happened.

One minute everything was working fine and the next all JS functionality has broken.

When  I click on any buttons on the page nothing happens anymore and no JS seems to be executed. As part of this project, you need to have the JS in an external file which is referencing at the bottom of the HTML file.

As it stands the page is very bare-bones as I was focusing on core functionality before I make it look nice with CSS.

I have gone over everything 3 times and can't see why it has stopped working. The project is due tonight and I'm hoping someone here can spot what I have missed/done to break it.

To clarify the HTML and JS files are in the same directory on my PC which is why the source in the script tag is just the file name. The file name referenced in the script tag is 100% the right spelling. I'll paste in both the HTML and JS for you guys to see.

As StackOverflow only seems to allow one set of code to be added per question and when pasted in completely the JS looks a mess and is hard to read I'm going to cut out most of it and leave it in one simple function to show how I'm structuring the JS in case I did something wrong there.

```js
function superSize() {
  alert("For health and saftey reasons we would like to inform you that this burger is very large and should be consumed in portions!")
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title> Order Online </title>
  <h1> Welcome to Finnegans new restaurant & bar </h1>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <form name="login">
      <tr>
        <!-- this adds a new row to the table -->
        <td> Username: </td>
        <!-- the data contained in the first row -->
        <td> <input type="text" id="uname" size="30" /> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Password: </td>
        <td> <input type="password" id="pword" size="30" /> </td>
        <!-- password is masked when typing into the form -->
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="login()" /> </td>
        <!-- login button. when selected it calls the login function from the external JS file -->
      </tr>
    </form>
  </table>

  <label for="burgers"> Please select a burger: </label>
  <!-- label that goes in front of the dropdown menu -->
  <select id="burgers">
    <!-- the dropdown box and its 3 options -->
    <option value="large"> 6oz Large &euro;7 </option>
    <option value="extra"> 10oz Extra-Large &euro;9 </option>
    <option value="super" onclick="superSize()"> 16oz Supersize &euro;17.50 </option>
    <!-- when this option is selected the "superSize" function is called from the external JS file -->
  </select>


  <form name="coupon">
    <label> Discount Codes: </label>
    <input name="DiscountCode" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Check Code" onclick="checkDiscount()" />
  </form>


  <!-- below is the links to the external CSS and JS files. they are at the bottom of the document for faster loading and better search engine optimisation -->
  <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
  <link href="external.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the browser's console for error messages? When you look at the source code in the browser (Ctrl+U) and click the underlined `src` of your <script>, can you see the file?

Comment: You cannot have  `h1` inside `head`; it must be moved to `body`.

Comment: @ChrisG I didnt know you could do that. very handy. I checked and when i click on the underlined src it does open the JS file and inside I can see the code. Im guessing then this means that the files not seeing each other is not my issue then?

Comment: No, the file is linked fine. My guess is that your JS code has a syntax error, which will break the entire script. Did you check the developer tools console yet? press F12

Comment: @connexo fixed. thanks for spotting and letting me know

Comment: you need to listen to `change` event on the `select`.

Comment: None of that is code-breaking; you should use the `<select>`'s `onchange` event though. (and assign it in your JS code, not inline)

Comment: @ChrisG Im aware that the onchange event will execute a command when it detects a change in something (in this case the dropdown box) but I wanted it to change only for one option selected and not all. Or did you mean put an onchange attribute to the "supersize" option in the dropdown? aka:

<option value="super" onselect="superSize()"> 16oz Supersize &euro;17.50 </option>

Comment: No, but you can check which option was selected inside the onchange handler: `if (this.value === "super")`

Comment: @ChrisG on your previous comment regarding the dev tools (f12) what would i be looking for there? Im aware of it but have never used it before.

Comment: You need to open the console tab, press F5 to refresh the page and look for errors. Web dev without the console is like driving a car while blind.

Comment: You cannot nest a `FORM` inside the `TABLE` element as you do here -- the `form` must either wholly contain the `table` or itself be wholly contained within a single `td` cell

Comment: form input elements should have ( but not compulsory ) a `name` attribute. The ID will not appear in any POSTed data unless done so with ajax or similar

Comment: Add the Javascript that you feel is messy when added and it will be edited

Comment: @ChrisG thats console tab is very useful. I didnt know about that either. so you were bang on it caught one error which was a syntax error in the JS file.  when i select it it points to the first lines of one of my JS functions as the issue though I still dont see the problem. the variable is declared and initialised as far as  can tell. Ill try paste the code in here if I can.<br/><br/>''' function login(){
 var EnteredUsername = document.forms.["login"]["uname"].value;
}''' The error is pointing to the second line, where i initialised/declared EnteredUsername.

Comment: add code to the question, not comments

Comment: the reason that javascript fails is the form does not have an input named `uname` - if it did you could simply use `document.forms.login.uname.value;`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I was trying but im not sure how to

Comment: under the question you should see an `Edit` hyperlink

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius is that not it here: <td> <input type="text" id="uname" size="30" /> </td>

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i saw that and tried using ' and also 3 of them incase it was like pasting code in the question

Comment: that is an ID rather than a name. Form elements use names to address them whereas the ID is really to aid Javascript/css

Comment: the `onclick` assigned to an `option` in the `select` menu is also not correct. The function should be on the `select` itself

Comment: The problem is here: `var EnteredUsername = document.forms.["login"]["uname"].value` there's a period after `forms`, but you're using square bracket notation. Use one or the other, not both.